# WaitHandle.WaitAll в Closing (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Есть следующий код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<ManualResetEvent> events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        test();
    }
    public void test()
    {
        var resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        arg =>
        {
            HandleConnection();
            resetEvent.Set();
        });

        events.Add(resetEvent);
    }
    public void HandleConnection()
    { }
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());
    }
}
```

При закрытии окна, все выглядит хорошо, окно закрывается. Но если в `MainWindow()` добавить вызов `test()` еще раз, то при закрытии окна, приложение зависает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем дело и как это поправить. Я так понимаю, что зависание вызвано тем, что `WaitAll()` не завершается из-за того, что не для всех элементов списка events вызывается `Set()` и скорей всего, это связано с некорректным добавлением `ManualResetEvent` в список.

Comment: А если убрать вызов `HandleConnection`? Код выглядит правильно.

Comment: @VladD та же ситуация, если убрать вызов HandleConnection

Comment: Окей, а внутри `Window_Closing`, сколько элементов находится в `events`? Два или может быть больше?

Comment: @VladD только что проверил, 2 элемента при двух вызовах test() соответственно

Comment: Окей. Тогда попробуйте вернуть назад `HandleConnection`, и внутри этого метода написать `Debug.WriteLine("hello")`. Интересно, сколько раз выведется в итоге текст.

Comment: @VladD так же, дважды. Более того, добавил в начале вызова Window_Closing вызов .Set() у всех элементов списка events, но результат тот же

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответ здесь:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239609/c-sharp-threads-waithandle-waitall

`WaitHandle.WaitAll()` не работает в `STAThread` в случае, если количество ожидаемых элементов `ManualResetEvent` больше одного.

По ссылке выше так же приведено альтернативное решение, которое помогло разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: Ох, хорошо заметили. Тогда может быть имеет смысл пользоваться не ManualResetEvent'ами, а перейти на Task, тогда должно работать. Но в любом случае блокировать UI-поток — плохая идея, так что вам стоило бы поменять стратегию.